# Laravel Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-facade

I am new to Laravel and checking out some sample code.

In a controller I see this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class RegistrationController extends \BaseController {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('guest');
}
```

Why do I have to use the "**use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;**" ?

Cant I just use eg Input::get(); like I do in my route file?

Comment: Do you know about PHP's namespace?

Comment: Yeah, but how come I dont need it in my routes file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class RegistrationController extends \BaseController {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('guest');
}
```

this controller is in global namespace. so you don't need to use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;` you can directly call `Input::get('foo');`

```
<?php namespace Foo; //<---- check the namespace

    use Input;

    class RegistrationController extends \BaseController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('guest');
    }
```

here you can write either, `use Input` or `\Input::get('foo')` while calling.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use importing namespaces (you don't need to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;`) here.

You can accesss Input facade, using `Input::get('something')` as long as your controller is in global namespace. Otherwise you need to use `\Input::get('something')` or add `use Input` after `<?php`.

Comment: So no need for it as long I extend the basecontroller?
I found the code here: https://github.com/BnSmth/email-verification/blob/master/app/controllers/RegistrationController.php

Comment: @user2722667 There is no need to use it here. Remember that not all codes or libraries are well written. Anyone can post anything to github.